# Socket programming in c

Tags: c, algorithm, winsock, winsock2

I want to ask **how the server file** in c is contact with **client file** in socket programming in c?

when I run the server file it stops at listen() function and wait..

when I run the client file it makes the server file to continue running and move to accept function in server file.

but I don't know how the two files communicatee with each other?
This is the two files Server.c and Client.c

Server.c

```
`
    #define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
    #pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib") 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <io.h>
    #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <InetReg.h>
    #define PORT    9909
    
    
    struct sockaddr_in sockAddress;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    
    int main() {
        int socketfd ;
        struct addrinfo hints;
    
        
        WSADATA wsaData;
    
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
            printf("Failed intialize wsa\n");
        else
            printf("Success intialize wsa\n");
        //Create socket
        
    
        
        socketfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if (socketfd == -1)
            printf("fails socket creation");
        else
            printf("Succness socket creation");
        
        
        
        
        
        
    
        
        //intailize address of sockaddress
        memset(&sockAddress, 0, sizeof(sockAddress));
        sockAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sockAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        sockAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        
    
        //Bind the socket to local port
    
        int bindfd = bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sockAddress,sizeof(sockAddress));
        if (bindfd == -1)
            printf("Fail Binding socket to local port\n");
        else
            printf("Success Binding socket to local port\n");
    
        //listen the request from client
        int listenfd = listen(socketfd, 1); //return 0 means success
        if (listenfd != 0)
            printf("Fail listening\n");
        else
            printf("start listening to local port\n");
    
    
        //accepting
        
        memset(&clientAddress, 0, sizeof(clientAddress));
        int clientAddressLength=sizeof(clientAddress);
        int clientSocketfd = accept(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress,&clientAddressLength);
        if (clientSocketfd == -1)
            printf("failed to accept");
        else
            printf("Accepted...");
        //Writing
    
        char msg[100] = "Hello my name is ahmed server";
        unsigned int i = sizeof(msg);
        //_write(socketfd,msg,i);
        send(clientSocketfd, msg, sizeof(msg), true);
        //printf("sent: %s\n", msg);
        printf("\n\n\nServer address: %d\n\n\n", sockAddress.sin_addr.s_addr);
        printf("ServerAddress: %d\n", clientSocketfd);
        
        //close
        
        closesocket(clientSocketfd);
        closesocket(socketfd);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
        system("pause");
        
        return 0;
    }
```

`

Client.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib") 


#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define PORT 9909



struct sockaddr_in SocketAddress;


int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        printf("Failed intialize wsa\n");
    else
        printf("Success intialize wsa\n");
    
    //intialize socket

    int SocketFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (SocketFd == -1)
        printf("Failed intialize socket\n");
    else
        printf("Success intialize socket\n");

    //intialize socket address
    memset(&SocketAddress,0,sizeof(SocketAddress));
    SocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SocketAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    SocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    
    
    //connectivity 
    int c = connect(SocketFd,(struct sockaddr*)&SocketAddress,sizeof(SocketAddress));
    printf("client: %d", SocketFd);


    printf("\n\n\nClient address: %d\n\n\n", SocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr);
    return 0;

    

}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/) related article?

Comment: Assuming you mean TCP/IP sockets, the libs are specific to the OS. So you need to specify which OS and library you are using.

Comment: i am using the particular library and use TCP/IP

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel sorry, I use winsock library in c and now i edit my question and attach my code  here.

Comment: @Ahmedgamalseliman: I have removed the incorrect tag for you, since you do not appear to be using the "Socket.IO" library that is intended for JavaScript.

Comment: The client should check the return value of [`connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect), to determine whether it was successful. It the function call was successful, the client should call [`recv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recv) to read the data that the server is sending it.

Comment: In `Server.c`, the line `send(clientSocketfd, msg, sizeof(msg), true);` does probably not do what you want. It will send all 100 bytes of the array `msg`, which consists of 29 bytes of text and 71 bytes with the value `0`. It would probably be more meaningful to only send the first 29 bytes, i.e. `strlen(msg)` instead of `sizeof(msg)`. The expression `strlen(msg)` will evaluate to `29` whereas the expression `sizeof(msg)` will evaluate to `100`.

Comment: It would be even better to send 'strlen(msg)+1, though such an end-of-line NUL is not required at OP stage of development.